# How get the color format in Opencv?

Tags: opencv, iplimage

In C++, how can I get the color format (RGB or BGR for example), from an object `cv::Mat` or `cv::IplImage`?

Comment: As far as I know you can not. cv::imread give you bgr pixels in case of a color image. And when using cv::cvtColor you have to track it on your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image type is not part of the image specification in OpenCV.
The user needs to know and track the actual color format.
In most cases, this is not a problem since ultimately the format of the source of the image is known.
As a rule of thumb, most RGB image sources (webcams, files etc.) are represented as BGR, but you should check your particular domain.